# how to draw a rectangle in specific postion in android

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

I am trying to draw rectangle inside a Rectangle.
I am expecting the child to draw in lower side of parent rectangle but opposite is happening. Actually i found there that, inside canvas.drawRect there is no specific position to decide where to draw. May be I am missing something because of new in android.
This is the api I am using-

```
canvas.drawRect(x+(x/3)+rM.x(), y/9, w-rM.width(), h/5, paint);
```

Following the getting and expected screenshot

[image]

Following are the coordinates I am getting -

```
For bigger rectangle - 
x      - 234
y      - 89
width  - 593
height - 627


For smaller Rectangle
rm.x      - 39
rm.y      - 8
rm.width  - 49
rm.height - 30
```

I used the formula-

```
canvas.drawRect(x+(x/3)+rM.x(), y/9, w-rM.width(), h/5, paint);
```

- {x,y,w,h>} belongs to 1st set of data
- rm.{x,y,w,h} belongs to 2nd set of data

Comment: You are clearly using the wrong coordinate system for the vertical axis. Perhaps you are expecting the origin to be at the bottom of the display.

Comment: Check the coordinates with a debugger or with a log statement. Are they what you expect?

Comment: which parameter of the drawRect carries that , because as I found its Left , Top , Right , Bottom , where is the axis

Comment: this is the signature of drawRect: `public void drawRect (float left, float top, float right, float bottom, Paint paint)`, which numbers did you use for left, top, right, and bottom?

Comment: @Henry updated the question , as you asked

Comment: This gives top=9.89 and bottom=125.4 so clearly not fully inside the bigger rectangle.

Comment: there I am getting confused , can you just give me the ideal input for top and bottom .. then I can understand how this rectangle thing working.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39138/discussion-between-bunta-and-henry)

Comment: my bottom should be height-rm.Height .. but then my top goes beyond the main rectangle .. there I am stuck

Comment: yup got it... Top needed to refine.. thanks

Answer (score 6):

For the future viewers -

you can create rectangle object and then pass it to `drawRect()` method. Example -

```
Rect rect = new Rect();
rect.left = x;
rect.top = y;
rect.right = x + width;
rect.bottom = y + height;

canvas.drawRect(rect, paint);
```